# Получение данных из БД MySQL. Java

Tags: java

```
    public void SignIn() {

    System.out.print("Login : "); String sign_login = in.next();
    System.out.print("Password : "); String sign_pass = in.next();

    try {
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String sql = "select * from loginin where Login = '" + sign_login + "' and Password = '" + sign_pass + "'";
        ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while (results.next()) {
            if (results.getString(1).isEmpty()){
                System.err.println("Wrong login or password !!!");
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Проблема в том что if не работает по какой-то причине.

Comment: Значит строка не пустая?

Comment: Я пробовал узнать её длину - results.getString(1).length() - но на экране нечего не появилось, даже 0. Не понимаю что с этой строкой

Comment: @AlexanderChernin

Comment: так может у вас вот это `results.next()` возвращает false?

Comment: @Никита если не появилось даже 0 , значит там null

Comment: у вас точно есть столбец с наименованием "1" ? тогда правильнее будет results.getString("1")

Comment: @VitalyM - Это как ?

Comment: @tym32167 - у меня есть БД в которой таблица на 2 столбца : Login & Password. Суть в том что если в БД нет логина и пароля который ввел пользователь в консоли должно появится Wrong login or password !!!

Comment: то есть если в БД нет нужной вам записи, то ваш запрос с БД не вернет ничего и вот это `results.next()` будет `false`, то есть `if (results.next() == false){ System.err.println("Wrong login or password !!!");   }` должно сработать ?

Comment: @tym32167 сработало

Comment: @Никита куда бы оно делось, всё же логично :)

Comment: @tym32167 - а можно вам как-то в личку написать ? Есть пару вопросов не по теме

Comment: @Никита смысла не имеет, я не программирую на java. Если у вас вопросы по программированию, задавайте их нак сайте.